# Getting the largest value for each group in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table that is something like this...

```
 person    |   account    |   accountbalance
--------------------------------------------
  1               a             100
  1               b             250
  1               c             283
  2               a             25
  2               b             199
  3               a             65
```

and for each person, I need to find the account that has the highest balance. I am doing this right now:

```
SELECT person, account, accountbalance FROM mytable
AND accountbalance=  
    (SELECT MAX(accountbalance) FROM mytable);
```

But this only returns the ONE top account among them all, not for each person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to compute the max in a derived table and join with that:

```
SELECT mytable.person, account, accountbalance 
FROM mytable
JOIN (
  SELECT person, MAX(accountbalance) MaxAccountBalance 
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY person
) t ON mytable.person = t.person
   AND mytable.accountbalance = t.MaxAccountBalance;
```

or you could do a correlated subquery in the where clause (which is what you almost did - you just missed the necessary correlation):

```
SELECT person, account, accountbalance 
FROM mytable m1
WHERE accountbalance = (SELECT MAX(accountbalance) FROM mytable WHERE person = m1.person);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a3212/5)

Answer (score 0):

For `MYSQL`, you can try this way also

```
select * 
from (select * from mytable order by `person`, accountbalance desc, account) x
group by `person`
```